# Pressing tab for word completion in command line mode switches to search mode in Vim

Tags: vim

When loading a file, lets call it `foobar.txt`, like so:

```
:b foo<tab>
```

Where `<tab>` is me pressing the tab key, **sometimes** I am redirected from the command line (`:`) to the search prompt (`/`) but other times it works fine. I am having trouble recreating the exact situation, but I know that I have had this same problem with at least these three commands:

1. `:badd`
2. `:b`
3. `:vsplit`

Can anyone tell me why this would ever happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is something related to your termcap (does tab do anything weird when you're in normal/insert mode?), but if it's specifically related to interacting with the filesystem it could be something else. Have you tried a different termcap and/or using the gui version instead of the console version to see if the issue is reproducible?

Comment: how would I go about using a different termcap?

Comment: I second that this is something weird.  I think this is a good thing to take to the Vim mailing list, with a dump of `:ver` and other info about your platform.